# Do Rails' Devise, AuthLogic, Restful Authentication all use the same method names or mechanism such as current_user and session[:user_id]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authlogic, restful-authentication

I see similar usage all the time, even in Rails guide such as http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

For example, `current_user` returns the current logged in user,  `logged_in?` returns whether there is a logged in user, `@current_user` stores
the logged in user (so no need to look into DB again), `session[:user_id]` stores the user id
of the current logged in user so as to know what the logged in user is on a second or later webpage request (need to look into DB), `remember_token` is the users table field to check against `cookies[:auth_token]`,
so as to remember the user even when the user closes the browser (so the session ends and session cookie disappears)

Do Devise, AuthLogic, and Restful Authentication all use these names / mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think they don't because restful uses logged_in? while devise uses user_signed_in?  where user can be replaced by your model...